# how to protect php pages properly

Tags: php

i have a php pages that is protected by a login, i've put the code below on all of my php pages

```
<?PHP
session_start();
session_destroy();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: infralogin.php");
}
?>
```

i have my main page where its being routed after i logged in,

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="center"><a href="tickettracker.php">Ticket Uploader</a></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="center"><a href="raptool.php">RAP Tool</a></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="center"><a href="login/add_user.php">Add User</a></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="center"><a href="login/logout.php">Logout</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></td>
</table>
```

now this tickettracker.php has sub-pages which i access thru a link inside it,below are the sample links inside it,

```
<tr>
<td width="135"><strong>Ticket Source:</strong></td>
<td align="left"><select name="Ticket" id="Ticket">
<option value="tickettracker.php" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
<option value="wireless_new.php">Wireless - Remedy</option>
<option value="smp_backend.php">SMP - Backend</option>
<option value="ess_remedy.php">ESS - Remedy</option>
<option value="wireline_remedy.php">Wireline - Remedy</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>

<p align="center"><a href="view_transactions.php">View Transactions</a> | <a href="report_generator.php">Report Generator</a></p>
<tr align="center">
<p align="center">External Link: <a href="raptool.php">RAP Tool</a></p></td>
```

i tried putting in the code below in all of the sub-pages, to protect them which works because i cant access them and im being routed to the login page, but the thing is whenever im already logged in and i clicked on tickettracker.php to access the sub- pages, im being redirected still to the login page

```
<?PHP
session_start();
session_destroy();
if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: infralogin.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of !(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != ''), you can do !empty($_SESSION['login']), it checks both.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
     header ("Location: infralogin.php");
 }
```

instead of this, use the following reasoning and it should work :-)

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == '') {
   header ("Location: infralogin.php");
}
```

Thanks to MrCode. Remove the

```
session_destroy();
```

too. as it's destroying the current session so the current session data will be missing.

Comment: +1 Half correct, you're just missing the session destroy issue

Comment: this code doesn't work: `if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == '')) {
   header ("Location: infralogin.php");` because it allows me to access the page even if im not logged in.
}

Comment: The parenthesis are in the wrong place, it should be `if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == '')`

Comment: +1 MrCode. . . updated. . .

Comment: thanks for the help as well @Muhammed Hedayet

Answer (score 2):

The condition should be:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == '')
```

This is saying: if login is NOT set OR login is blank/missing, then redirect.

**You also have a authentication bypass issue** because you don't `exit()` after the redirect. You should use:

```
session_start();
//session_destroy(); // <-- removed
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] == '') {
    header ("Location: infralogin.php");
    exit();
}
```

If you don't `exit()` after the redirect, the user can choose to ignore the redirect and thus bypass your login system and receive the protected page contents.

As @Jim pointed out, you are calling session_destroy, why? Even though it won't be destroyed until the end of the script this will still produce a bug in your system when the user tries to advance to another protected page (they will be logged out).

Comment: im already using this code `session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == '') {
    header ("Location: infralogin.php");
    exit();
}` , but its still redirecting me to the login page...:(

Comment: It should be `||` not `&&`, try copying and pasting from my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help...its working now, its the `session_destroy();` from my main page that i have not removed which is causing to redirect again to the login page...but i should have this `session_destroy();`, right in order to destroy the session when i logout, because each sub-pages has its own log out button so i put the `session_destroy();`, please correct me if im wrong im new to php...

Comment: Yes that's correct as long as you're only calling destroy when the logout button is pressed.